# How to print a string that is inside an object in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object named promise and it has functions and string inside it. For printing the object i can use

```
console.log(promise);
```

but i have a string named `"responseText"` inside promise. If i try to print it using

```
console.log(promise.responseText);
```

,its showing as undefined. I can see the value of responseText by printing the object. But when i print using `promise.responseText` its showing undefined.

**FYI**

I am able to print all the `functions` inside `promise`, but I am not able to print the string. Please help.

Comment: `responseText !== responsetext`

Comment: I am printing it as console.log(obj.responseText); only. Editted the post.

Comment: Can you show how the object looks like?

Comment: Can you show your promise object

Comment: I suspect your promise is doing some async operation and is not completed at the time you did `console.log`. The classic async problem.

Comment: This is my promise object

{readyState: 1, 
getResponseHeader: ƒ,
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
setRequestHeader: ƒ,
overrideMimeType: ƒ,
 …}abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ (_func)
fail: ƒ (_func)
responseText: "The Value That i need"

Comment: Where do you print that object? Within a `setState()`?

Comment: seems like you have `.done` and `.complete` methods inside this promise so try using them: `promise.done(function(d){console.log(d)})`

Comment: i can able to print all the functions inside promise, but i m not able to print only string values inside promise. Other than that if i give console.log(promise.done); ,its printing the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var promise = {
  responseText: function(){
    return "responseText"
  }
}

console.log(promise.responseText())
```

OR

```
var promise = {
  responseText: function(){
    console.log("responseText")
  }
}

promise.responseText()
```